# Nodejs callback hell in foreach

Tags: json, node.js, express, mongoose

i have a venues data. i want to get how people in here now after that compress venues data and count data to json. This code is working but json result is null.

```
var _venues = _.map(venues.response.venues, function (v) {
    Checkin.where({
            'venuesUniqeId': v.Id,
            'createdDate': {
                $gte: new Date().getHours() - 2
            }
        })
        .count(function (err, hereNow) {

            return new Venue({
                'uniqeId': v.id,
                'name': v.name,
                'count': hereNow
            });
        });
});
return r.json(_venues);
```

Comment: if i don't send mongoose query for instance remove Checkin.where()... only return value it is work but i need count

Comment: Is Checkin.where an asynchronous function?

Comment: Checkin.where is mongoose query that is http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a good understanding of what the `map` function is: Map takes a set of inputs and 1-to-1 transform them into something different. In this case, your `_venues` array is empty because you are not returning anything inside the `_.map` callback.

The way that I have always tackled a problem like this is to use a promises library like `bluebird` or `Q` and leverage the `.all` method. In this case your _.map is not outputting the actual `_venues` but `_venuePromises` which you later execute and wait for an array of venues. In other words, because of the asynchronous nature of mongoose, the output of `Checkin.where` is not a collection of venues but a collection of promises.

DISCLAIMER: I do not use mongoose so I am not sure about how it integrates with either Q or Bluebird.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var _venuePromises = _.map(venues.response.venues, function (v) {
    return Checkin.where({
            'venuesUniqeId': v.Id,
            'createdDate': {
                $gte: new Date().getHours() - 2
            }
        })
        .count(function (err, hereNow) {

            return new Venue({
                'uniqeId': v.id,
                'name': v.name,
                'count': hereNow
            });
        });
});

Promise.all(_venuePromises).then(function (actualVenues) {
  return r.json(actualVenues);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`_.map` is synchronous. For this, you need an asynchronous alternative like [`async.map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#maparr-iterator-callback). Also, I'm not sure this really constitutes "callback hell".

Comment: i try async.map but i can't solve this problem. i need combine venues data and count data